# Quick method to enumerate two big arrays?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, enumerate

I have two big arrays to work on. But let's take a look on the following simplified example to get the idea:

I would like to find if an element in `data1` is matched to an element in `data2` and return the array index in both `data1` and `data2` if a match is found in form of a new array `[index of data1, index of data2]`. For example, with the below set of `data1` and `data2`, the program will return:

```
data1 = [[1,1],[2,5],[623,781]] 
data2 = [[1,1], [161,74],[357,17],[1,1]]
expected_output = [[0,0],[0,3]]
```

My current code is as follow:

```
result = []
for index, item in enumerate(data1):
    for index2,item2 in enumerate(data2):
        if np.array_equal(item,item2):
            result.append([index,index2])
>>> result
[[0, 0], [0, 3]]
```

This works fine. However, the actual two arrays that I am working on has 0.6 million items each. The above code would be extremely slow. Is there any method to speed up the process?

Comment: How long are your rows and what type are the entries?

Comment: Length of each row is 2. And the entries inside the rows are integers. The array is like data1 = [[1,1], [2,5], [623,781], [164,75], .... ], around 0.6 million rows in total.

Comment: Sorting the arrays could reduce complexity to `O(n log n)`, or you could do the comparison in NumPy directly, rather than the for-loop in Python.

Comment: How large can these integers be? Are they all positive?

Comment: You should be able to use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist), if you have enough memory to store each pair-wise distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the fastest, but easy and reasonably fast: use KDTrees:

```
>>> data1 = [[1,1],[2,5],[623,781]] 
>>> data2 = [[1,1], [161,74],[357,17],[1,1]]
>>>
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree
>>>
>>> def intersect(a, b):
...     A = KDTree(a); B = KDTree(b); X = A.query_ball_tree(B, 0.5)
...     ai, bi = zip(*filter(itemgetter(1), enumerate(X)))
...     ai = np.repeat(ai, np.fromiter(map(len, bi), int, len(ai)))
...     bi = np.concatenate(bi)
...     return ai, bi
... 
>>> intersect(data1, data2)
(array([0, 0]), array([0, 3]))
```

Two fake data sets `1,000,000` pairs each takes `3` seconds:

```
>>> from time import perf_counter
>>> 
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 100000, (1000000, 2))
>>> b = np.random.randint(0, 100000, (1000000, 2))
>>> t = perf_counter(); intersect(a, b); s = perf_counter()
(array([   971,   3155,  15034,  35844,  41173,  60467,  73758,  91585,
        97136, 105296, 121005, 121658, 124142, 126111, 133593, 141889,
       150299, 165881, 167420, 174844, 179410, 192858, 222345, 227722,
       233547, 234932, 243683, 248863, 255784, 264908, 282948, 282951,
       285346, 287276, 302142, 318933, 327837, 328595, 332435, 342289,
       344780, 350286, 355322, 370691, 377459, 401086, 412310, 415688,
       442978, 461111, 469857, 491504, 493915, 502945, 506983, 507075,
       511610, 515631, 516080, 532457, 541138, 546281, 550592, 551751,
       554482, 568418, 571825, 591491, 594428, 603048, 639900, 648278,
       666410, 672724, 708500, 712873, 724467, 740297, 740640, 749559,
       752723, 761026, 777911, 790371, 791214, 793415, 795352, 801873,
       811260, 815527, 827915, 848170, 861160, 892562, 909555, 918745,
       924090, 929919, 933605, 939789, 940788, 940958, 950718, 950804,
       997947]), array([507017, 972033, 787596, 531935, 590375, 460365,  17480, 392726,
       552678, 545073, 128635, 590104, 251586, 340475, 330595, 783361,
       981598, 677225,  80580,  38991, 304132, 157839, 980986, 881068,
       308195, 162984, 618145,  68512,  58426, 190708, 123356, 568864,
       583337, 128244, 106965, 528053, 626051, 391636, 868254, 296467,
        39446, 791298, 356664, 428875, 143312, 356568, 736283, 902291,
         5607, 475178, 902339, 312950, 891330, 941489,  93635, 884057,
       329780, 270399, 633109, 106370, 626170,  54185, 103404, 658922,
       108909, 641246, 711876, 496069, 835306, 745188, 328947, 975464,
       522226, 746501, 642501, 489770, 859273, 890416,  62451, 463659,
       884001, 980820, 171523, 222668, 203244, 149955, 134192, 369508,
       905913, 839301, 758474, 114597, 534015, 381467,   7328, 447698,
       651929, 137424, 975677, 758923, 982976, 778075,  95266, 213456,
       210555]))
>>> print(s-t)
2.98617472499609
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it with the fake dataset and it works. However, when I try it with the actual dataset, it forces the IDLE shell to restart. Not so sure for the reason behind becuase no error message was displayed.

Comment: @yukchingleung the one thing I could imagine would be memory, if there are non-uniques with large multiplicity in both datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Because your data is all integers, you can use a dictionary (hash table), time is 0.55 seconds for the same data as in Paul's answer.  This won't necessarily find all copies of pairings between `a` and `b` (i.e. if `a` and `b` themselves contain duplicates), but it's easy enough to modify this to do that or to make a second pass afterward (over just the matched items) to check for other occurrences of those vectors in the data.

```
import numpy as np

def intersect1(a, b):
    a_d = {}
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        a_d[x] = i
    for i, y in enumerate(b):
        if y in a_d:
            yield a_d[y], i

from time import perf_counter
a = list(tuple(x) for x in list(np.random.randint(0, 100000, (1000000, 2))))
b = list(tuple(x) for x in list(np.random.randint(0, 100000, (1000000, 2))))
t = perf_counter(); print(list(intersect1(a, b))); s = perf_counter()
print(s-t)
```

For comparison, Paul's takes 2.46s on my machine.

Comment: This should work for float too right? Just add 0.5 to the output of `randint` to check. Yes, Python can hash lists of floats just fine.

Comment: It should, yes, if you're looking for exact equality between floats.  Typically with floats, though, you'd want equality within some threshold, and then a KDTree or similar would be better.

Comment: Your answer is not correct. Try to check on OP's dataset and you will find out. Use `intersect1(data2,data1)`.

Comment: It's correct.  The difference is that mine assumes the data is a list of tuples coming in, not a list of lists (because lists aren't hashable).  If I convert OP's dataset to a list of tuples I get the right answer.

Comment: Did you try `intersect1(data2,data1)`? Not `intersect1(data1,data2)`. It is not the issue of lists or tuples.

Comment: Ah you're right, it doesn't find multiple duplicates.  I'll make a note of that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** *The other answers, using a dictionary (for checking exact matches) or a KDTree (for epsilon-close matches), are much better than this—both much faster and much more memory-efficient.*

Use [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist). If your two data arrays have `N` and `M` entries each, it will make an `N` by `M` pairwise distance array. If you can fit that in RAM, then it's easy to find the indexes that match:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

# Generate some data that's very likely to have repeats    
a = np.random.randint(0, 100, (1000, 2))
b = np.random.randint(0, 100, (1000, 2))

# `cityblock` is likely the cheapest distance to calculate (no sqrt, etc.)
c = cdist(a, b, 'cityblock')

# And the indexes of all the matches:
aidx, bidx = np.nonzero(c == 0)

# sanity check:
print([(a[i], b[j]) for i,j in zip(aidx, bidx)])
```

The above prints out:

```
[(array([ 0, 84]), array([ 0, 84])),
 (array([50, 73]), array([50, 73])),
 (array([53, 86]), array([53, 86])),
 (array([96, 85]), array([96, 85])),
 (array([95, 18]), array([95, 18])),
 (array([ 4, 59]), array([ 4, 59])), ... ]
```