# Finding nearest neighbors for the multiple target point from dataset using Sklearn KD-Tree

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, kdtree

I am trying to learn how this sklearn kd-Tree works and I am finding trouble to understand it.

lets say I have these coordinates in lat and long

```
60.46717,21.69396
60.44987,21.70151
60.44936,21.67614
60.45198,21.64994
60.47137,21.63471
60.49294,21.63467
60.49918,21.61378
60.49462,21.63038
```

and lets say I have these two target coordinates.

```
60.46722,21.69395
60.46525,21.63649
```

Now I want to use Kd-Tree algorithm and try to find which are the nearest coordinates for those target coordinates.

For example may be these three coordinates are the nearest to 60.46722,21.69395

```
60.46717,21.69396
60.44987,21.70151
60.44936,21.67614
```

And rest of the coordinates are nearest to 60.46525,21.63649.

I dont need the exact code, but any explanation on how do I use multiple target position and implement KD-Tree on the observation data would be helpful.

SO far, I have found example of finding nearest neighbors on one target coordinates /points.

Comment: [scipy.spatial.KDTree.query](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html) accepts "An array of points" as input, is this answering your question?

Comment: Same holds true for [sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.query](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.query), but is this indeed what you ask?

Comment: thank you, I will check those articles. Yes my question was, how to use KdTree for multiple target coordinates / points and write all those nearest neighbors point related to each target coordinates

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49912284/500207 for an example of using KDTrees to do just this.