# Difficulty with numpy broadcasting

Tags: numpy, distance, linear-algebra

I have two 2d point clouds (oldPts and newPts) which I whish to combine. They are mx2 and nx2 numpyinteger arrays with m and n of order 2000. newPts contains many duplicates or near duplicates of oldPts and I need to remove these before combining.

So far I have used the histogram2d function to produce a 2d representation of oldPts (H). I then compare each newPt to an NxN area of H and if it is empty I accept the point. This last part I am currently doing with a python loop which i would like to remove. Can anybody show me how to do this with broadcasting or perhaps suggest a completely different method of going about the problem. the working code is below

```
npzfile = np.load(path+datasetNo+'\\temp.npz')
arrs = npzfile.files
oldPts = npzfile[arrs[0]]
newPts = npzfile[arrs[1]]

# remove all the negative values 
oldPts = oldPts[oldPts.min(axis=1)>=0,:]
newPts = newPts[newPts.min(axis=1)>=0,:]

# round to integers
oldPts = np.around(oldPts).astype(int)
newPts = newPts.astype(int)

# put the oldPts into 2d array
H, xedg,yedg= np.histogram2d(oldPts[:,0],oldPts[:,1],
                         bins = [xMax,yMax], 
                         range = [[0, xMax], [0, yMax]])
finalNewList = []
N = 5
for pt in newPts:

    if not H[max(0,pt[0]-N):min(xMax,pt[0]+N),
         max(0,pt[1]- N):min(yMax,pt[1]+N)].any():
        finalNewList.append(pt)

finalNew = np.array(finalNewList)
```

Comment: Can you post the `npz` input file or fake it somehow so we have a complete example to test against?

Comment: here is a link to the npz file https://www.dropbox.com/s/z3owtdpvjt0o74g/temp.npz?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to use linear algebra to compute the distance between each pair of 2-long vectors, and then accept only the new points that are "different enough" from each old point: using [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html):

```
import numpy as np
oldPts = np.random.randn(1000,2)
newPts = np.random.randn(2000,2)

from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
dist = cdist(oldPts, newPts)
print(dist.shape) # (1000, 2000)

okIndex = np.max(dist, axis=0) > 5
print(np.sum(okIndex)) # prints 1503 for me

finalNew = newPts[okIndex,:]
print(finalNew.shape) # (1503, 2)
```

Above I use the Euclidean distance of 5 as the threshold for "too close": any point in `newPts` that's farther than 5 from all points in `oldPts` is accepted into `finalPts`. You will have to look at the range of values in `dist` to find a good threshold, but your histogram can guide you in picking the best one.

(One good way to visualize `dist` is to use `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(dist)`.)

This is a more refined version of what you were doing with the histogram. In fact, you ought to be able to get the exact same answer as the histogram by passing in `metric='minkowski', p=1` keyword arguments to `cdist`, assuming your histogram bin widths are the same in both dimensions, and using 5 again as the threshold.

(PS. If you're interested in another useful function in `scipy.spatial.distance`, check [out my answer that uses `pdist` to find unique rows/columns in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38653131/500207).)

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to answer, however it may be the right way  and the obvious way to do it but it is 3 times slower than the way I have shown and I hope to speed that up if I can work out the broadcasting. The timings in a jupyter notebook where 50.1 ms ± 5.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) and 152 ms ± 973 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) The use of kdtrees may produce a better time but I am not an expert.

Comment: Yup, kd-trees are great: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49912284/500207 for the opposite problem—the question is about finding the same points in the two arrays, but you can readily adapt it to finding different points. Yes, `cdist` is doing a lot more work than you need (since if you find a single point in `oldPts` that's too close to a point in `newPts`, you can eliminate it right away, instead of enumerating *all* other old points).